# Does PHP echo wait for rest of script

Tags: php, echo

Does the php's echo wait to send data to the screen, until the rest of the script is complete?

So if I have:

```
<?

echo "Hello World";

$xmlData = file_get_cotents("www.webpage.com");

        $myFile = "data_backup.xml";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        $stringData =  $xmlData;
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        fclose($fh);
?>
```

So does the above sample what to show Hello World until the contents from the url are retrived and saved locally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep. unless you flush the data with `flush();`

Comment: So using flush how would I make sure that my "Hello World" is sent while the rest of the process runs?

Comment: thanks for the info +1  but I am still seeing a delay in the output until the script completes. Not sure if there are any other options?

Answer (score 0):

All of the scripting in PHP occurs before the page loads, so the answer to your question is: yes, it would wait until the file is retrieved and saved before showing "Hello World".